# Affecting variables in different classes in Java

Tags: java, variables, scope, pass-by-value

I have two classes that I'm trying to manipulate one variable with, as an example

```
public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        while(game_over[0] == false) {
            System.out.println("in the while-loop");
        }
        System.out.println("out of the while-loop");
    }

    static boolean[] game_over = {false};
}
```

and

```
public class B {

    public boolean[] game_over;

    public printBoard(boolean[] game_over) {

        this.game_over = game_over;
    }

    public void run() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            // do something
        }
        game_over[0] = true;
        System.out.println("GAME OVER");
    }
}
```

The code snippets provided are not meant to be actual workable code, I'm more concerned with the concept. In my program, class A creates a thread that utilizes class B, and I want class B to affect the variable 'game_over' such that the while-loop in class A will be affected by the change... any idea how I can successfully update the variable? Thanks.

Comment: What's the point of having an external variable? why not define a method B.isGameOver()?

Comment: @MauricePerry I don't know laroy's reasons, but generally, there may be many components that can decide that the game is over,and to avoid A having to check each and every component that could make this decision, it's actually a good idea to provide a level of indirection.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt OK, well in that case, pass them an object of class GameStatus or GameMonitor, not a boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use an array for this, that makes it harder to ensure a data-race free application.

Since you want to be able to pass around the `game_over` flag as an independent object, the easiest way to achieve a correct multi-threaded application is to use the `AtomicBoolean` class.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

class B {
    private AtomicBoolean game_over;

    public B(AtomicBoolean game_over) {
        this.game_over = game_over;
    }

    public void run() {
        // do stuff
        game_over.set(true);
    }
}
```

and in your class A:

```
public class A {
    static AtomicBoolean game_over = new AtomicBoolean();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        Thread t = new Thread(b);
        t.start();

        while (!game_over.get()) {
            System.out.println("in the while-loop");
        }
        System.out.println("out of the while-loop");
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer. Another option is to declare game_over to be `volatile`

Comment: I can see how this would work but am having trouble creating the AtomicBoolean in Class A

Comment: @alfasin That would only work if it wasn't an array. Because it's an array, the volatile only affects the read action on the game_over array reference, but not the later write action to the first element of the array - so there's still no guarantee that the main loop in class A will see the update.

Comment: True that, in my mind I was not using an array but a simple `boolean` value :)))